# "> was unexpected at this time." - batch/command script

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, scripting

I'm using the batch script below:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=" %%I in ('FTP -s:%FTPFIL% > log.txt') DO SET /A FTPNUM=%%I
```

and get an error:

```
> was unexpected at this time.
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 3):

Put your entire command into doublequotes

```bat
('"FTP -s:%FTPFIL% > log.txt"')
```

Or escape the redirection with a caret

```bat
('FTP -s:%FTPFIL% ^> log.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks, Compo. That went well

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=" %%I in ('FTP -s:%FTPFIL% ^> log.txt') DO SET /A FTPNUM=%%I
```

the `>` needs to be escaped with `^` because it has higher prio than the FOR command.

Comment: Thanks, npocmaka. That went well